# Accessing to JS-widget from module

Tags: ruby, cucumber, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I try to access to custom JS-widget from my module.
Base page class just include PageObject, DataMagic and RSpec::Matchers.

My class

```
require_all 'lib/pages/billing/billing_form_panel.rb'

class RealtyCpBillingPage < BasePage
    include BillingFormPanel
end
```

Module

```
require_all 'lib/widgets/jquery_datepicker.rb'

module BillingFormPanel
    include PageObject

    button :show_datepicker, class: 'ui-datepicker-trigger'

    jquery_datepicker :datepicker, id: 'ui-datepicker-div'

    def datepicker
        datepicker_element
    end

    def select_packet data
        if data['date']
            show_datepicker
            data['date'] = data['date'].split(' ').reverse
            datepicker.year = data['date'][0]
            datepicker.month = data['date'][1]
        end
    end
end
```

JQuery UI datepicker widget

```
class JQueryDatepicker < PageObject::Elements::Div

    include PageObject

    PageObject.register_widget :jquery_datepicker, JQueryDatepicker, :div

    def month month
        select_list_element(class: 'ui-datepicker-month').select month
    end

    def year year
        select_list_element(class: 'ui-datepicker-year').select year
    end
end
```

And steps:

```
Если(/^если выбираю тариф:$/) do |table|
  on(RealtyCpBillingPage).select_packet table.hashes.first
end
```

When run this test, I see the following error:

```
  Unable to pick a platform for the provided browser (RuntimeError)
  ./lib/pages/billing/billing_form_panel.rb:22:in `datepicker'
  ./lib/pages/billing/billing_form_panel.rb:34:in `select_packet'
```

So, How can I access to that Widget from my Module?

UPD: Browser start here `hooks.rb`.

```
Before do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
    @browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 8
end

After do
    @browser.close
end
```

Comment: Is there anything else in the base class other than the includes?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. BasePage just contains that includes.
Also, when I added datepicker element to the page directly - it works fine. But I need to access that from my module

Comment: The error message says there is a problem with starting the browser. Please share the code that starts the browser.

Comment: Updated post. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to include PageObject in widget class.
The full answer is here
https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/173